# what is the difference between visibility and display in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm confused with these two terms which are used in CSS. What is the difference between visibility and display in CSS?

Comment: You must have missed [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) whilst searching on google. Let's not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I'd go for MDN rather than W3Schools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In layman's terms, `visibility` determines if the element is rendered on screen but does not affect how layout is performed (i.e. how the browser calculates where each element goes on the screen and how much space it takes up).

On the other hand, `display` specifically controls how the element is laid out on the page; this affects its visible status "as a side effect" because `display: none` means "do not include this element in the layout at all".

For a more technically-oriented explanation you should look up the documentation for these properties on MDN ([`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility), [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display)) or read the W3C specification ([here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#visibility) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop)).

Answer (score 1):

In general, `visibility` property decides whether **show**, **hide** (make your element transparent) or **collapse** (remove your element from the view).

The `display` property, not like its name, decides **how** the browser arrange this elements: like an *inline*, a *block*, a *table*, ...

You can search in any online reference resource for more details.